# How to get duplicated values fom map<String, List<OBJECT>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map<String, List object>>
And I am trying to get keys with duplicated list values

---

Example:

"One"=[object, object1],

---

"Two"=[object2, object3],

---

"Three"=[object, object1],

Should return :

"One"=[object, object1]

---

"Three"=[object, object1]

Comment: How do you define duplication? Objects cannot generally be compared for any equality other than reference equality. If that’s fine then just use `groupingBy`

Comment: I use my custom comparator for objects and duplication for this case is to have two entries with the same list of values

Comment: If you have a custom comparator, then you should document that in your question. How do you define that the values in a list are the same? How do you determine whether two values are the same? Does order matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a HashMap, How to filter it based on duplicate values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671039/given-a-hashmap-how-to-filter-it-based-on-duplicate-values-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Create a `Map<List<Object>, String>`.  As long as Object properly overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` the lists can be compared.  Any `key` of the original list that references the same set of list objects will be grouped based on that duplicate list.  For two lists to be equal, the lists must have the same order.  So I sorted each list before building the final map.  Thus `List<A,B> and list<B,A>` will be considered equal.

```
List<Object> list1 = List.of("MyObject1", "MyObject2");
List<Object> list2 = List.of("MyObject2", "MyObject3");
List<Object> list3 = List.of("MyObject1", "MyObject2");
List<Object> list4 = List.of("MyObject2", "MyObject1");
map.put("One", list1);
map.put("Two", list2);
map.put("Three", list3);
map.put("Four", list3);

Map<List<Object>, List<String>> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<Object>>(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream().sorted().toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.toList())));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[MyObject2, MyObject3]=[Two]
[MyObject1, MyObject2]=[One, Four, Three]
```

So keys `One, Three, and Four` refer to lists with the same count of the same objects.  So all that is needed is to iterate across the maps values and find out which list of the keys has size greater than one.  I did not attempt to build a final map since I did not know which key would want to choose for a given duplicate list.